# pandas equivalent of sql UPDATE table SET col3 = NULL WHERE col1 != col2

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find pandas equivalent of ...

```
UPDATE table SET col3 = NULL WHERE col1 != col2
```

I tried...

```
df[df['col1'] != df['col2']]['col3'] = None
```

but seems like it has no effect...!
please help!

Comment: ``df.loc[lambda x: x.col1 != x.col2, ,'col3'] = np.nan`` . Again, it is much easier if you provide sample data

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['col1'].ne(df['col2']), 'col3'] = np.nan`